# Table generated by hibernate but not showing in mysql database

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate

Hi I am working on code of book called `Master Spring MVC` and I am using `Mysql Database` instead of `embeded database`. In book author have used `xml` based configuration but I am using java based. Till here everything is working fine.

The problem I am facing is that when I am running my code in `tomcat` server and with the logs (hibernate logs for table generation for particular table) everything is fine but the table is getting generated in my database but not this table called `historic`. I have attached my code along with log which shows that table is generated:

Please not this is a multi module project and therefore webapp, database is configured separately.
1) Hibernate Log to genrerate particular table

Hibernate log for class:

```
create table historic (
   historic_type varchar(31) not null,
    id integer not null auto_increment,
    adj_close double precision,
    change_percent double precision,
    close double precision not null,
    from_date datetime,
    high double precision not null,
    interval varchar(255),
    low double precision not null,
    open double precision not null,
    to_date datetime,
    volume double precision not null,
    ask double precision,
    bid double precision,
    index_code varchar(255),
    stock_code varchar(255),
    primary key (id)
) engine=MyISAM
```

2)Database configuraton file

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("edu.zipcloud.cloudstreetmarket.core.entities")
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class JpaHibernateSpringConfig {
    private Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());

    public DataSource dataSource() {
        logger.info("============================[Data Source Configuration: Began]");
        BasicDataSource ds = new BasicDataSource();
        ds.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        ds.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost/cloudstreet");
        ds.setUsername("root");
        ds.setPassword("root");

        logger.info("============================[Data Source Configuration: Ends]");
        return ds;
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean localContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean() {
        logger.info("============================[LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean: Began]");
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean bean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        bean.setDataSource(dataSource());
        bean.setPersistenceUnitName("jpaData");
        bean.setPackagesToScan("edu.zipcloud.cloudstreetmarket.core");
        bean.setPersistenceProviderClass(HibernatePersistenceProvider.class);
        bean.setJpaProperties(hibernateJPAProperties());
        logger.info("===========================[LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean: Ends]");
        return bean;
    }

    public Properties hibernateJPAProperties() {
        logger.info("============================[hibernateJPAProperties: Began]");
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect");
        properties.put("hibernate.show_sql", "true");
        properties.put("hibernate.format_sql", "true");
        properties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "create");
        properties.put("hibernate.naming-strategy", "org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy");
        properties.put("hibernate.default_schema", "public");

        logger.info("============================[hibernateJPAProperties: Ends]");
        return properties;
    }

    @Bean
    public JpaTransactionManager jpaTransactionManager() {
        logger.info("============================[jpaTransactionManager: Began]");
        JpaTransactionManager manager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        manager.setEntityManagerFactory(localContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean().getObject());
        logger.info("============================[jpaTransactionManager: Ends]");
        return manager;
    }
}
```

2) DispatcherServlet:

```
public class DispatcherServletConifg extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[] { JpaHibernateSpringConfig.class };
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[] { WebServletInit.class };
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[] { "/" };
    }
```

3) Historic entity

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "historic_type")
@Table(name = "historic")
public abstract class Historic implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -802306391915956578L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    private double open;

    private double high;

    private double low;

    private double close;

    private double volume;

    @Column(name = "adj_close")
    private double adjClose;

    @Column(name = "change_percent")
    private double changePercent;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "from_date")
    private Date fromDate;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "to_date")
    private Date toDate;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(name = "interval")
    private QuotesInterval interval;
```

Please take a look at logs and if you need any other information let me know.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think problem is mysql keyword is being used as column name "interval"
try some other name

we can rename interval field like below

```
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
@Column(name = "quotesinterval")
private QuotesInterval interval;
```

OR

any name which matches to your need.

Bottom line is should not use any [mysql keywords](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/keywords.html)

Comment: can you add actual solution to your answer, So I can accept it

Answer (score 0):

I tried that generated sql query as suggested by `Ashish` turned out that `interval` was not supported as field type so I changed my field name a little bit and it started working but still not sure if that wasen't supported. Configuration should have thrown a error

I changed `@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(name = "interval")
    private QuotesInterval interval;` 
to

`@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(name = "`'interval`'") //<-- here
    private QuotesInterval interval;`

there is slight **tick** inside `@column()` that worked.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me... **verify entity name.**

Double-check that you're querying the correct table name in mysql. This happened to me, but *I had been querying the class name, rather than the table name*.

```
 @Entity
 @Table(name= "Account") // select * from Account, not AccountDetails
 public class AccountDetails implements Serializable { /* class info */}
```